# How to convert String "[7, 9]" to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this string. (I'm getting Comma Separated Character String from Backend)

```
"seasons": "[7, 9]"
```

I want to iterate the array of Array like this.

```
// example
this.props.data.seasons.map((element) => console.log(element));
```

How do we convert "[7, 9]" to Array [7, 9]?

Is it usual for you guys to handle array string?

Comment: Do you have any control over the backend? Cause I would class this as a bug...

Comment: yes I'm making my own backend! And I think it's most simple and easy way to handle arrays in Django :)

Comment: Yes I think passing data as string is okay, and you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to convert it back and forth

Comment: If you're making your own backend - then you should fix your backend to return a json array rather than a string containing one. Django huh? Then use `json.dumps()` on your entire data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert JavaScript object.

```
const tempDict = {"seasons": "[7, 9]"}
JSON.parse(tempDict.seasons)
```

Comment: Cool! What is the return value of the JSON.parse(tempDict)?

Comment: It will be a JS object

Comment: @JohnBaek Please make sure tempDict is actually a string `( JSON.stringify(..` before giving to `JSON.parse(..` but again you will end up in JSON object like `{season: "[7, 9]"}`

Comment: @RajaSimon can you edit your question? Also I'm getting error when it's attempt to convert "" to array. How can I handle this edge case?

Comment: Vote up my question too!

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse(element)`:

```
let newArray = JSON.parse(this.props.data.seasons);
console.log(newArray[0]);  //printing 7, ryt ?
```

See [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Perfect but I couldn't iterate this.props.data.seasons. Almost worked, voted up your answer

Comment: And as others said, it would be a lot easier if you converted the whole object to a JSON string, so that you can use a single `JSON.parse` to parse the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some cosmetic work like below:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
             var mystr = "[7, 9]";
             mystr = mystr.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
             var myArray = mystr.split(",");

             for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                console.log(jQuery.trim(myArray[i]));
            }
        });
   </script>
```

Comment: Yeah! Hard Coding also works but using JSON.parse seems better option. Voted up